# Can you sand jointer infeed and outfeed tables?

Tags: tool-maintenance, jointer, thickness-planer

My jointer tables are not stainless material, so they develop rusty spots. I already removed most of it using a rust-removing liquid product, but there are still some die-hard remnants.

*Would it be OK to remove this rust with very fine sandpaper? An orbital sander even?*

I want to prevent this thing from happening in the future. I am considering either:

1. **hydrodesulfurized kerosene** (the single ingredient on a self-proclaimed jointer table lubricant)
2. **rustproof artificial resin-based paint**
3. **rustproof lacquer**

The problem with the 1. is that the surface must be rust-free before application. The problem with 2. and 3. is that they are not transparent (brown and black).

*Would any of these surface treatments offset the (possible) sins I would commit by sanding the tables?*

Comment: Yes. We already have an Answer that covers this (and likely more than one about what to do to prevent a recurrence — any of the tool-care Answers is likely to cover good options for keeping rust at bay.

Comment: There's also [this related one](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3099/how-to-clean-and-maintain-my-table-saw-top) with a link at the bottom should you wish to make your own paste wax for upkeep and lubrication.

Comment: @Graphus yes, thank you!